# Hiding Visual Studio toolbar while coding

Tags: visual-studio, toolbar

is there a way to hide the Visual Studio toolbar only while coding? For example, when I'm on the Designer page I'm gonna need the toolbar to edit the GUI, but it's useless when coding, so I only want to hide it while coding.

Comment: you can do `Shift + Alt + Enter` to full screen, is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Why is this question tagged with c#, winforms and computer-science? None of these seems appropriate.

Comment: @BentTranberg click on `Edit (1)` and you will see someone has removed these tags, since that person has not enough rep we need to approve the edit. Click on it and approve the edit and the tags will be gone

Comment: Done. I also chose to comment since we have a new user. I understand choosing tags isn't necessarily that easy always, but I suspect they were chosen to broaden the target audience. The problem with that is that tags become devaluated.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you mean Toolbox, if not my apologies.

You can set it to auto-hide by left clicking and picking the appropriate option. This should hide it once you are done selecting the Control.

Comment: Yes, I meant Toolbox, I'm sorry for that.
What should I left click, though?